# Is it ok to define ejb session bean references in a superclass

Tags: session, ejb-3.0

I have many session bean classes used in my service classes. It is painful to define session bean references every time I need in a service class.

Hence, I am just wondering if I can use like below. Are those EJBs initialized when I initialize MyService class even if I need only SessionBean1? If so, this might be overkill.

```
public class BaseService {
    @EJB
    protected SessionBean1 ejb1;
    @EJB
    protected SessionBean1 ejb2;
    @EJB
    protected SessionBean1 ejb3;
}

@Stateless
public class MyService extends BaseService {
    public void methodA() {
        super.ejb1.findAll();
    }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the specifications require containers to support superclass injection.

It depends what you mean by "initialize".  If you're creating MyService instances yourself, then injection won't work at all; MyService needs to be created by the container (be a servlet, CDI bean, EJB bean, etc.).  Then, the container obviously must do some work to create a proxy object to inject into the field, but it might not create the actual bean instance.  For stateless session beans, the actual bean instance might not be created or allocated from a bean pool until a method is actually called.  For stateful session beans, the container will create an instance when MyService is created.

Comment: Yes, MyService itself is a session bean too (edited source code above). So, in the example above, only SessionBean1 is created or allocated from pool? That is what I want to know. I might have tens of session beans but want to declare references in super class (BaseService). Then I can use any session bean in other service classes without having to declare session bean references. Would like to know if this is an acceptable approach.

Comment: It depends whether or not SessionBean1 is a stateless session bean.  If it is, then it should be fine to inject references that you don't need.

Comment: Yes, SessionBean1 is also a stateless. Thank you.